# spring 2.5.6 DI issue in jsf application

Tags: spring, jsf-2, dependency-injection

i get NPE(null pointer exception) each time when i try to insert data into database. help me to resolve this issue. i have import all the necessary libraries which are requried for spring. 
this is my applicationContext.xml file where i have configure all the beans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="personService" class="com.ecommerce.assignment.service.PersonService">
    <property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO" />
</bean>
<bean id="personBean" class="com.ecommerce.assignment.bean.PersonBean" />
<bean id="personDAO" class="com.ecommerce.assignment.dao.PersonDAO" />
</beans>
```

**this is interface of person DAO.**

```
public interface IPersonDAO {
    public void addPerson(Person instance);
}
```

**this personDAO class implementing IpersonDAO interface and its unimplemented methods.**

```
public class PersonDAO implements IPersonDAO {

        @Override
        public void addPerson(Person instance) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction().begin();

            session.saveOrUpdate(instance);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

this is interface personService.
    public interface IPersonService {
        public void addPerson(Person instance);
    }

```
   public class PersonService implements IPersonService,Serializable {
        private IPersonDAO personDAO;

        public IPersonDAO getPersonDAO() {
            return personDAO;
        }

        public void setPersonDAO(IPersonDAO personDAO) {
            this.personDAO = personDAO;
        }

        @Override
        public void addPerson(Person instance) {
            getPersonDAO().addPerson(instance);
        }
}

public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private String username;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{personService}")
    private IPersonService iPersonService;

public void addPerson(){
        try{
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setUsername(getUsername());
            person.setEmailAddress(getEmailAddress());
            person.setPassword(getPassword());
            iPersonService.addPerson(person);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what variable exactly is `null`. Please update the question accordingly. Or is your concrete problem that you don't understand what a `NullPointerException` means?

Comment: @BalusC, it is iPersonService which gives NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your person bean is managed by Spring, you should use `@Autowired` annotation to make dependency injection, or inject it via XML, as you did for `PersonService`. You can as well declare the bean as `@Component` and `@Scope`.

You error is in injecting service in a bean by using JSF's `@ManagedProperty` annotation that works solely within JSF context, that is, with JSF managed beans, annotated with `@ManagedBean`, or declared via XML.